# Integrating IBM JRules ILOG with Websphere Commerce Ver 7

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

I have followed the below mentioned steps to integrate IBM JRules ILOG with Websphere Commerce Ver 7 :-

1) Installed IBM Ilog Jrules Studio 7.1.1 & Rule Execution Server.

2)Installed Rule Execution Server on Websphere Application Server(Ver 7).

[Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.install.doc/Content/Business_Rules/Documentation/_pubskel/JRules_Application_Servers/ps_Installing_JRules_IC99.html)

3) Configured WebSphere Commerce to communicate with WebSphere ILOG JRules

[Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/tasks/tpijrulesconfigurecont.htm)

4) Imported the sample rule project into rule studio and deployed to the Rule execution Server.

5) Created new external price rule in Management center in order to fetch the deployed rules(in previous step) from rule execution server.

But when I am searching for the external rule in management center using '*', none of the rules could be fetched from RES. I do not have any exception in WAS console.

Is there other additional steps that I need to follow ?